# Write custom object to .plist in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsobject, nscoding

I am blocking into something and I am sure it is too big. 
I have a custom object that look like this

```
 @interface DownloadObject : NSObject <NSCoding>{
    NSNumber *key; 
    NSString *name; 
    NSNumber *progress; 
    NSNumber *progressBytes; 
    NSNumber *size; 
    NSString *path; 
}
@property (copy) NSNumber *key; 
@property (copy) NSString *name; 
@property (copy) NSNumber *progress; 
@property (copy) NSNumber *size; 
@property (copy) NSString *path; 
@property (copy) NSNumber *progressBytes; 
-(id)initWithKey:(NSNumber *)k name:(NSString *)n progress:(NSNumber *)pro size:(NSNumber *)s path:(NSString *)p progressBytes:(NSNumber *)pb; 
@end
```

And the implementation

```
  @implementation DownloadObject
@synthesize size, progress, name, key, path, progressBytes;

-(id)initWithKey:(NSNumber *)k name:(NSString *)n progress:(NSNumber *)pro size:(NSNumber *)s path:(NSString *)p progressBytes:(NSNumber *)pb  
{
    self.key = k;
    self.name = n; 
    self.progress = pro; 
    self.size = s; 
    self.path = p; 
    self.progressBytes = pb; 

    return self; 
}

-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder*) coder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.key = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Key"] retain];
        self.name = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Name"] retain];
        self.progress = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Progress"] retain];
        self.size = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Size"] retain];
        self.path = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Path"] retain];
        self.progressBytes = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"ProgressBytes"]retain]; 
    }
    return self;
}


-(void) encodeWithCoder: (NSCoder*) coder {
    [coder encodeObject:self.key forKey:@"Key"]; 
    [coder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"Name"]; 
    [coder encodeObject:self.progress forKey:@"Progress"]; 
    [coder encodeObject:self.size forKey:@"Size"]; 
    [coder encodeObject:self.path forKey:@"Path"]; 
    [coder encodeObject:self.progressBytes forKey:@"ProgressBytes"]; 
}


-(void)dealloc
{
    [key release]; 
    [name release]; 
    [size release]; 
    [progress release]; 
    [path release]; 
    [progressBytes release]; 
    [super dealloc]; 
}

@end
```

As you can see it implement NSCoding (I think so, NSObject does not conform to NSCoding). Now when I try to do something like that just to test

```
downloadArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]retain];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]; 
DownloadObject *object = [[DownloadObject alloc]initWithKey:number name:@"hey" progress:number size:number path:@"hey" progressBytes:number]; 
[downloadArray addObject:object]; 
[object release]; 
[downloadArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

`downloadArray` is a `NSMutableArray`. My plist read/write is fine, the `path` is located in the application support and when I log it show the plist path.

But it just does not write the array to the plist, any idea ?

Comment: Why you set the retainCount of downloadArray to 2? Only need  

downloadArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Answer (score 21):

Property list files can only store basic data types and cannot contain custom objects. You need to convert your object to an `NSData` object if you want it to be written to the plist. You can do this with `NSKeyedArchiver`, which will encode an object which conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol into an `NSData` object.

```
DownloadObject *object = [[DownloadObject alloc]initWithKey:number name:@"hey" progress:number size:number path:@"hey" progressBytes:number];
NSData* objData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
[downloadArray addObject:objData];
[object release];
```

When you want to reconstruct your object from the `NSData` object, you use `NSKeyedUnarchiver`:

```
NSData* objData = [downloadArray objectAtIndex:0];
DownloadObject* object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:objData];
```

You also have several memory leaks in your code. In your `-initWithCoder:` method, you should not be using accessors to set the value of the ivars, you should just set the ivars directly, like so:

```
key = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"Key"] copy];
```

You are calling `-retain` and then using the accessor which is specified as `copy`, which will mean your object has a retain count of 2 and will not be released. In general you should avoid using accessors in init methods.

Also, in the code where you allocate your `downloadArray` object, you are calling `-alloc` and then `-retain` on the object, which will leave it with a retainCount of 2. You should re-read the Objective-C [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).

Comment: does it worth it? I mean, is this more productively  than just convert properties to dictionary and save as dictionary? Why I need wrap my object to nsdata or is there some recommendations about this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

[archiver encodeObject:highScoreArray forKey:kHighScoreArrayKey];

[archiver finishEncoding];

[data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

[data release];
[archiver release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL flag = false;

    ObjectFileClass  *obj = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];

   //TO Write Data . . .

    NSData* archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj.title];
    flag =[archiveData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
}


if (flag) {
    NSLog(@"Written");

  //To Read Data . . .

    NSData *archiveData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    id yourClassInstance = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archiveData]; // choose the type of your class instance  . . .
    NSLog(@"%@",yourClassInstance);
}else{

    NSLog(@"Not Written");
}
```