# Can a core data model be added to an SDK project?

Tags: iphone, ipad, static-libraries, core-data-migration

I am developing a sdk(static library for iOS) for other users/developers. I have to some data and persist it for a long time. So I have to use core data along with the sqlite database in this project. My question is while at the end building SDK will the xcdatamodel object will be hidden from users of this SDK or I have to use something other than core data.

My requirement is to hide the coredatamodel object from users of this SDK. How can I implement that. I will be sharing headers that users/developers can use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to persist data besides coredata, such as plists. In this case I think it is better to use something like that rather than coredata. Otherwise you will have problems coordinating contexts, models, etc.

Comment: Thank you.I did store the data using plist. Now I have one more question. Is that possible to add one of my own written model class object into a plist. From the documentation I got the idea that only NSArray, NSDictionary like stuffs are the things that we can store/add to a plist. How can I add one of my model class object to plist. Or is there any other mechanisms to store model objects?. I prefer please give an information using plist itself.

Comment: Check the first answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569207/write-custom-object-to-plist-in-cocoa