# Replace NS objects array with a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, plist, nsobject

This is my first time posting so I apologize if I miss a guideline or two. Feel free to call me out. Anyways. I'm currently slowly trying to learn objective-c and iOS/xcode and as such am doing a ton of tutorials. I came across one and have been working through it but wanted to try and challenge myself and make some tweaks. Ultimately this is a learning process. So my primary question is as follows:

In objective-C using Xcode, how does one replace a custom class with NSObjects with a plist?

Here is the snippet of code that I'm trying to figure out how to replace with a plist that has all the same information:

```
@implementation RecipeBookViewController {
    NSArray *recipes;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
 //   recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

    Recipe *recipe1 = [Recipe new];
    recipe1.name = @"Egg Benedict";
    recipe1.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe1.imageFile = @"egg_benedict.jpg";
    recipe1.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 fresh English muffins", @"4 eggs", @"4 rashers of back bacon", @"2 egg yolks", @"1 tbsp of lemon juice", @"125 g of butter", @"salt and pepper", nil];

    Recipe *recipe2 = [Recipe new];
    recipe2.name = @"Mushroom Risotto";
    recipe2.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe2.imageFile = @"mushroom_risotto.jpg";
    recipe2.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 tbsp dried porcini mushrooms", @"2 tbsp olive oil", @"1 onion, chopped", @"2 garlic cloves", @"350g/12oz arborio rice", @"1.2 litres/2 pints hot vegetable stock", @"salt and pepper", @"25g/1oz butter", nil];

    Recipe *recipe3 = [Recipe new];
    recipe3.name = @"Full Breakfast";
    recipe3.prepTime = @"20 min";
    recipe3.imageFile = @"full_breakfast.jpg";
    recipe3.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 sausages", @"100 grams of mushrooms", @"2 rashers of bacon", @"2 eggs", @"150 grams of baked beans", @"Vegetable oil", nil];

    Recipe *recipe4 = [Recipe new];
    recipe4.name = @"Hamburger";
    recipe4.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe4.imageFile = @"hamburger.jpg";
    recipe4.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"400g of ground beef", @"1/4 onion (minced)", @"1 tbsp butter", @"hamburger bun", @"1 teaspoon dry mustard", @"Salt and pepper", nil];

    Recipe *recipe5 = [Recipe new];
    recipe5.name = @"Ham and Egg Sandwich";
    recipe5.prepTime = @"10 min";
    recipe5.imageFile = @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg";
    recipe5.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 unsliced loaf (1 pound) French bread", @"4 tablespoons butter", @"2 tablespoons mayonnaise", @"8 thin slices deli ham", @"1 large tomato, sliced", @"1 small onion", @"8 eggs", @"8 slices cheddar cheese", nil];

    Recipe *recipe6 = [Recipe new];
    recipe6.name = @"Creme Brelee";
    recipe6.prepTime = @"1 hour";
    recipe6.imageFile = @"creme_brelee.jpg";
    recipe6.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 quart heavy cream", @"1 vanilla bean, split and scraped", @"1 cup vanilla sugar", @"6 large egg yolks", @"2 quarts hot water", nil];

    Recipe *recipe7 = [Recipe new];
    recipe7.name = @"White Chocolate Donut";
    recipe7.prepTime = @"45 min";
    recipe7.imageFile = @"white_chocolate_donut.jpg";
    recipe7.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"3 1/4 cups flour", @"2 teaspoons baking powder", @"1/4 teaspoon salt", @"2 beaten eggs", @"2/3 cup sugar", @"2 ounces melted white chocolate", @"1/2 cup milk", nil];

    Recipe *recipe8 = [Recipe new];
    recipe8.name = @"White Chocolate Mocha";
    recipe8.prepTime = @"5 min";
    recipe8.imageFile = @"starbucks_coffee.jpg";
    recipe8.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2/3 cup whole milk", @"6 tablespoons white chocolate chips", @"coffee", @"whipped cream", nil];

    Recipe *recipe9 = [Recipe new];
    recipe9.name = @"Vegetable Curry";
    recipe9.prepTime = @"30 min";
    recipe9.imageFile = @"vegetable_curry.jpg";
    recipe9.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 tablespoon olive oil", @"1 onion, chopped", @"2 cloves garlic", @"2 1/2 tablespoons curry powder", @"2 quarts hot water", nil];

    Recipe *recipe10 = [Recipe new];
    recipe10.name = @"Instant Noodle with Egg";
    recipe10.prepTime = @"8 min";
    recipe10.imageFile = @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg";
    recipe10.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 pack of Instant Noodle", @"2 eggs", nil];

    Recipe *recipe11 = [Recipe new];
    recipe11.name = @"Noodle with BBQ Pork";
    recipe11.prepTime = @"20 min";
    recipe11.imageFile = @"noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg";
    recipe11.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 pack of Instant Noodle", @"BBQ pork", @"Salt and Pepper", nil];

    Recipe *recipe12 = [Recipe new];
    recipe12.name = @"Japanese Noodle with Pork";
    recipe12.prepTime = @"20 min";
    recipe12.imageFile = @"japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg";
    recipe12.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1 pack of Japanese Noodle", @"2 green onions", @"2 garlic cloves, minced", @"4 boneless pork loin chops", nil];

    Recipe *recipe13 = [Recipe new];
    recipe13.name = @"Green Tea";
    recipe13.prepTime = @"5 min";
    recipe13.imageFile = @"green_tea.jpg";
    recipe13.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Green tea", nil];

    Recipe *recipe14 = [Recipe new];
    recipe14.name = @"Thai Shrimp Cake";
    recipe14.prepTime = @"1.5 hours";
    recipe14.imageFile = @"thai_shrimp_cake.jpg";
    recipe14.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8 oz (250g) peeled and deveined raw shrimp", @"2 tablespoons red curry paste", @"1 large egg", @"2 teaspoon fish sauce", @"1 tablespoon sugar", @"2 tablespoons coconut milk", @"2 tablespoons roughly chopped Thai basil leaves", nil];

    Recipe *recipe15 = [Recipe new];
    recipe15.name = @"Angry Birds Cake";
    recipe15.prepTime = @"4 hours";
    recipe15.imageFile = @"angry_birds_cake.jpg";
    recipe15.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12 tablespoons (1 1/2 sticks) unsalted butter", @"2 1/2 cups all-purpose flour", @"1 tablespoon baking powder", @"1 teaspoon salt", @"1 3/4 cups sugar", @"2 large eggs, plus 3 large egg yolks", @"1 cup of milk", nil];

    Recipe *recipe16 = [Recipe new];
    recipe16.name = @"Ham and Cheese Panini";
    recipe16.prepTime = @"10 min";
    recipe16.imageFile = @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg";
    recipe16.ingredients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2 tablespoons unsalted butter", @"4 cups thinly sliced shallots", @"2 teaspoons fresh thyme", @"1/4 cup grainy Dijon mustard", @"8 slices rustic white bread", @"8 slices Gruyere cheese", @"8 ounces sliced cooked ham", nil];

    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipe1, recipe2, recipe3, recipe4, recipe5, recipe6, recipe7, recipe8, recipe9, recipe10, recipe11, recipe12, recipe13, recipe14, recipe15, recipe16, nil];
}
```

it is also referencing a custom made class Recipe.h and Recipe.m with code as follows:

recipe.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Recipe : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; // name of recipe
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *prepTime; // preparation time
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageFile; // image filename of recipe
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *ingredients; // ingredients

@end
```

Recipe.m

```
#import "Recipe.h"

@implementation Recipe

@synthesize name;
@synthesize prepTime;
@synthesize imageFile;
@synthesize ingredients;

@end
```

I'm honestly not sure if its even possible to do this, however I would like to be able to put all this information into a plist to be easily editable instead of having clunky code directly  in one of the .m files. Any and all help would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: This can help you-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569207/write-custom-object-to-plist-in-cocoa

Comment: I don't necessarily want to read/write the data to a plist file, I simply want to replace the data with a plist file. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish by moving this data to a plist. Where are you talking about editing this information? Not from within the app? Directly with a plist editor?

Comment: yes directly with a plist editor. I just want to be able to make the template more efficient so if I want to add more rows and data in later I just have to edit the plist. So if there's a way to move all of the recipe data into a plist I'd like to do that.

Comment: Then why plist? You can use database or coreData to manage everything more efficiently. Like `Recipe` as a coreData object..

Comment: That makes sense. I appreciate that feedback, but I would like to try this anyways. Is anyone able to offer suggestions on how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since all you properties are property list objects (strings and an array), you can convert your objects to an array of dictionaries. Just loop through recipes, and create a dictionary from each object:

```
NSMutableArray *recipeArray = [NSMutableArray new];

For (Recipe *obj in recipes) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [dict setObject:obj.name forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setObject:obj.prepTime forKey:@"prepTime"];
    [dict setObject:obj.imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];
    [dict setObject:obj.ingredients forKey:@"ingredients"];
    [recipeArray addObject:dict];
}
```

This will give you an array of dictionaries that will contain the same information as your objects. You can write that to a plist file with the array method writeToURL:atomically:.

Answer (score 0):

Select Project, Go to File --> NewFile --> Select Resource --> Select Plist Give some name & Click Ok.
Now add data to your plist.

use following code:

```
dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your Plistname" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Use this array where ever you want.

Comment: awesome! Could you be a little bit more specific of how that works with my data exactly in terms of referencing it etc?